# using lambda function to filter element value from list

Tags: python

how can I rewrite the following code by using lambda function?the problem i have is to make x as variable so I can return different list based on input

```
s_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
def f(x):
    return [a for a in s_list if a not in x]

print(f([1,2]))#[3,4,5,6]
print(f([4,6]))#[1,2,3,5]
```

Comment: Just curious why you ask this?

Comment: need to return a complicated list that filter some flied value

Comment: Which most likely means you don't want a lambda... how about you help saying what you really want to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need `s_list` like a argument, you can use this:

```
F = lambda x: [a for a in [1,2,3] if a not in x]
```

and if you need s_list like an argument, you could make this:

```
F = lambda x, s_list: [a for a in s_list if a not in x]
```

Comment: what if I would x to have default value as empty list, so if not x provide it, return all s_list?

Comment: @jacobcan118 As I describe in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49607920/7738328 it is possible to have default arguments also in `lambda` functions. Thus, you can do `lambda x=[]: ...` if you want a default argument. Note that default arguments need to be last in list, so either you have to have `s_list` as the first argument or just use `s_list`from the global (outer) scope.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to write your function using `filter`:

```
def f2(x):
    return filter(lambda a: a not in x, s_list)

print(f2(x=[1,2]))
#[3, 4, 5, 6]
print(f2(x=[4,6]))
#[1, 2, 3, 5]
print(f2(x=[]))
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or if you wanted it to be a function of both `s_list` and `x`:

```
def f3(s_list, x):
    return filter(lambda a: a not in x, s_list)

print(f3(s_list, x=[1,2]))
#[3, 4, 5, 6]
print(f3(s_list, x=[4,6]))
#[1, 2, 3, 5]
print(f3(s_list, x=[]))
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using Filter method :

```
s_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

x_=[1,2]

print(list(filter(lambda x:x not in x_,s_list)))
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```