# Python Tkinter Menu not executing on click

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, command

I have a menu that when clicked should run a function. There are no errors but when the user clicks on the menu it does not do anything.

After reading another stack overflow question I added in lamda functions to the command however it does the same thing both with and without the lambda. 
[Python Tkinter Menu Command Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306488/python-tkinter-menu-command-not-working)

```
menubar = Menu(self.master)
self.master.config(menu=menubar)

menubar.add_command(label = "Add Items", command= lambda: self.Add_Items)
menubar.add_command(label = "Make A Purchase", command= lambda: self.Transactions)
menubar.add_command(label = "Make A Return", command= lambda: self.Returns)
```

This is the menu

```
def Add_Items(self):
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Add Items")
    label.grid()
```

This is the function that it should run.

What am I missing?

Comment: The answer below by @FrainBr33z3 fixes the issue and the code runs (technically) however no labels are added to the frame despite me calling grid.

Comment: indeed it does. The label is drawn on the window with the text `Add Items`. Maybe there is an issue with some other part of your code. Anyhow, as the answer solves your problem, it is always better to open another question and not form a chain here

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to check it wasn't something stupid I had done. I will try and see what I have done @FrainBr33z3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs as there is a lack of parenthesis `()` in the `command` option with `lambda`. Do either one of the following:

```
menubar.add_command(label = "Add Items", command = Add_Items)
```

OR

```
menubar.add_command(label = "Add Items", command = lambda: Add_Items())
```